# ajax success doesnt alert anything

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have an AJAX request and if get id succeeds I would like to alert the data.

If I `print_r` my PHP function I get the correct result.

My ajax:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "getQuestions.php",
            datatype: "json",
            data:{
                compid:  id[4].innerHTML
            },
            success: function(response){
                alert(response);
            }

        });
```

My getQuestions.php:

```
<?php
include "functions.php";

getQuestions($_GET['compid']);
```

My function getQuestions($compid) in functions.php:

```
function getQuestions($compid){
    $int=intval($compid);
    $vastus=array();
    $conn = dbconnect();
    $sql="SELECT * FROM bet_question WHERE compid = $int";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            array_push($vastus,$row);
        } 
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
    return  json_encode($vastus);
}
```

If I do `print_r(getQuestions("some valid id"))` in `getQuestion.php` I get valid result and if I do `var_dump($_GET['compid'])` in `getQuestion` I'll get the correct id from ajax request.

If I check if the request is sent using inspect elements I get that request is sent with correct params, but the response is empty.

Comment: try to check this json_encode($vastus); have any value or not

Comment: use `error` callback of `ajax` and console error object

Comment: You have to use some output function like echo or exit to print the result

Comment: When the @Tushar say, you just expect the success, but you know if this getQuestions.php are returning correctly answer? put the error callback and try it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `return` you need to use `echo` and it should be updated as

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            array_push($vastus,$row);
        } 
          echo json_encode($vastus);
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
    exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to return the data, use echo instead, and set content type:

```
function getQuestions( $compid ) {

    $int=intval($compid);
    $vastus=array();
    $conn = dbconnect();
    $sql="SELECT * FROM bet_question WHERE compid = $int";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            array_push($vastus,$row);

        }

    } else {

        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;

    }

    @header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );
    echo json_encode( $vastus );
    exit;

}
```

Hope it helps